# Bash - Show dialog infobox while operation

Tags: bash, dialog

I'm scripting in bash for the first time. I'll crating a menu with dialog and add some function. I like to show a --infobox during a operation is running, so the user see something is happening.

The target is to have a dialogbox like

```
dialog --infobox "Please wait" 10 30
```

while the script is making the ping. If the ping is done, the --msgbox dialog opens.

```
test_rtt() {
ipSlave=$(awk '{ if($1~/'$SETSLAVE'/) print $2 }' $VARPATH/$VARCONFIGFILE)
    pingSlave=$(fping -c1 -t300 $ipSlave 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null)
    if ! [ "$?" = 0 ]
    then
        result="Loopbox (Slave) not found on $ipSlave"
        dialog \
            --backtitle "$VARBACKTITLE" \
            --title "$1" \
            --no-collapse \
            --msgbox "$result" $VARMENUHEIGHT $VARMENUWIDTH
    fi
    nrtest=$(awk '{ if($1~/'$SETNRTEST'/) print $2 }' $VARPATH/$VARCONFIGFILE)
    intervl=$(awk '{ if($1~/'$SETINTERVL'/) print $2 }' $VARPATH/$VARCONFIGFILE)
    result=$(ping -c $nrtest -i $intervl -U 192.168.74.93 | tail -1) #(HERE I WANT THE INFOBOX)
    dialog \
        --backtitle "$VARBACKTITLE" \
        --title "$1" \
        --no-collapse \
        --msgbox "$result" $VARMENUHEIGHT $VARMENUWIDTH
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get you correctly, you want to give the user the signal that "something is happening". I made two solutions. You can play with them.

1. The first one print the information before executing `$(fping..`
2. The second one uses `dialog --progressbox` to make progress box that is visible for the user.

I modified your code, so it pings 8.8.8.8 and checks if it's available.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
test_rtt() {
  dialog --infobox "Please wait" 10 30
  pingSlave=$(fping -c5 -t300 8.8.8.8 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null)
  # What is reason for introducing pingSlave var :)?
  if [ "$?" = 0 ]
  then
    result="Ping succeed for 8.8.8.8"
    dialog \
      --backtitle "test1" \
      --title "test2" \
      --no-collapse \
      --msgbox "$result" 50 50 
  fi
}
test_rtt_2() {
  fping -c5 -t300 8.8.8.8  | dialog --progressbox 50 50
  if [ "$?" = 0 ]
  then
    result="Ping succeed for  8.8.8.8"
    dialog \
      --backtitle "test1" \
      --title "test2" \
      --no-collapse \
      --msgbox "$result" 50 50 
  fi
}
test_rtt
dialog --clear
test_rtt_2
dialog --clear
```

I hope that this is what you expected :).

Comment: GREAT. Example 2 would be perfect. Almost.. I need the result of the first pipe in a variable (fping -c5 -t300 8.8.8.8). Like PIPESTATUS, but not the status i need the value (whole ping string).

Comment: If you want to get output of the command you can use following trick.

```temp_file=$(mktemp)        
fping... 8.8.8.8 | tee $temp_file | dialog --progressbox ...      
FPING_OUTPUT=$(cat $temp_file)       
```